# opening a *.bat file in a popup window in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, content-type

I need to open a *.bat file in a popup window. The way i do that is i open the popup window, which has a url set to the action of the downloading service.

The downloading service returns the following headers:

```
192.168.000.195.08080-192.168.000.201.52131: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="version.bat"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2009 14:54:09 GMT
Connection: close
```

At this point, all browsers that arent IE display the bat in the popup window, while IE 7 closes the popup immediately!

Question: what content-type should i return in order for IE to open the bat file in the popup (not present a download prompt)

Comment: For IE8, add "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff".  http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/09/02/ie8-security-part-vi-beta-2-update.aspx

For earlier IE browsers, you don't really have an easy workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time IE simply ignores the content-type and just goes for the file extension to figure out what it should do. I do not think you can circumvent this.

Maybe you should try setting it to text/html or something similar (text/xml) that really just has to be displayed.

Comment: @Niko: Edited your answer to remove the editorial on IE and Windows, which is unnecessary and contributes nothing to answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Handling MIME Types in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148.aspx) explains the steps Internet Explorer uses to determine how to handle a file.

As long as you are using Windows XP SP2 or later, and in *Tools* > *Internet Options...* > *Security* tab > *Custom Level...* > *Miscellaneous* > *Open files based on content, not file extension* is set to *Enable* for your content zone, you should get the behavior you want.